# I want to skip adding same values stored in array

Tags: java, arrays

I have added some array indexes in cardlist array. I want to avoid adding those indexes which 
have same value. What do I need to change?

```
playerHand.player_hand.add(cardList.get(lastCardIndex));
playerHand.player_hand.add(cardList.get(lastCardIndex - 1));
playerHand.player_hand.add(cardList.get(lastCardIndex - 2));
playerHand.player_hand.add(cardList.get(lastCardIndex - 3));
playerHand.player_hand.add(cardList.get(lastCardIndex - 4));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

> A collection that contains **no duplicate** elements.

Then you can use [Set#toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28%29):

> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this set.

You can also have an `ArrayList` from the `Set`:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(yourSet);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `Set` for this.

```
Set<Integer> cardIndexes = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

It guarantees the uniqueness of the values added to it.

If you need an array at the end you can use the `toArray()` method of `Set` to achieve this.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) you can find details about `Set`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use hashset like this.

```
HashSet <Integer> arr1=new HashSet<Integer>();
arr1.add(1);  
arr1.add(2);  
arr1.add(2);  
arr1.add(1);
```